# Successful share intent for android

Tags: android, android-intent

How can i tell if a user successfully completed a share intent? For instance if a user wanted to share an app via Facebook or Twitter.

Edit:

I am not looking at how to create an `Intent` for sharing. I want to know if the user actually shared anything. Or did the user hit the cancel button.

Comment: Why does your app need to know this?

Comment: I was looking to thank the user for sharing my app. But I don't want to thank them if they didn't share.

Comment: @adamp this information might be important for statistical reasons. it's nice to know where your content is shared most to optimize for that target.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think there is an assured way to do it.

You could initiate the send using `startActivityForResult()` and hope that the activity which handles the Intent replies with a `RESULT_OK`. But you can't rely on it to work always.

Comment: I guess i could just log.v the reply for each app that might be used and use a switch("reply for each app") from there.

Comment: hi, i have the same issue. can you please share your result if you succeed please. Thanks :)

Comment: I find that most sharing services respond with 0, which is no different than if the share is cancelled (also 0). Twitter returns -1 but that is it. Looks like we can't track shares :(

Comment: I tested WhatsApp, Signal, Twitter and Gmail and only WhatsApp returned RESULT_OK. All others returned RESULT_CANCELED.

Answer (score 3):

Found the option, suitable for Android >= 22. Maybe it can help somebody.

Starting with Android 22 there's an option to send `IntentSender` object in `createChooser` method. You can create a pending intent for a broadcast receiver in which you can get the package name of the app on which a user clicked.

Receiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    // do something here
}
}
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="MyReceiver" android:exported="false"/>
```

Creating pending intent:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And then using it in the chooser intent:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share
                            , "some_title"
                            , pendingIntent.getIntentSender()));
```

Then in `onReceiver` you can get the package name of the app:

```
String selectedAppPackage = String.valueOf(intent.getExtras().get(EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT))
```

Source: [medium blogpost](https://medium.com/code-with-lisa/get-results-from-android-chooser-9cfc5445a871)

Comment: But then again, this only tells what was the chosen app, not if the share was successful.

Answer (score 2):

For twitter - the "data" object in OnActivityResult is null when the user cancels the share.

Comment: For me, Twitter always return data null, even when the message sent

Answer (score -10):

You have use the `Intent.ACTION_SEND`, and the system will display a list of applications (on the device) where you can share. This website explains how:

http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/sharing-content-in-android-using-action_send-intent

Comment: I am not looking at how to create an intent for sharing. I want to know if the user actually shared anything. Or did the user hit the cancel button.