# Detect if user has completed Intent.ACTION_VIEW or just hit BACK

Tags: android

I have a webview and on click on some banner I am sending Intent.ACTION_VIEW to open browser or whatever user finds suitable like this:

```
  w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
         @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://")) {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                } else {

                    return false;
                }


            }

     });
```

Now what I want is to find a way to know if user just hit back button before opening browser or he actually opened browser. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793825/successful-share-intent-for-android) question but no solution there

Comment: "Not possible" is also a solution.

Comment: Like your attitude. All the best.

Comment: so you want to implement back key event for this webview?

Comment: No, when Intent starts you have an option to choose what application you want to use to complete Action.View and I want to know if user actually chose an option or hit back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one thing which may not be the best practice to use but I think this will solve your problem

Initialization => **boolean isPageLoading = false;**

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)  {                  

            return true;    
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            isPageLoading = false;             
        }
       public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            isPageLoading = true;
        }
    });
```

Now you have right indicator which will state, whether page is loading or not.

Now in your activity override back key press event

```
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) { // Back key pressed
                    if(isPageLoading){
                       // Do the tasks you want to do when page is loading
                    }else{
                       // Do the tasks you want to do when page loading is finished (or not in progress)
                     }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
```

Note that you can change the behavior of this functionality by adding more boolean variables which will indicate different status info (such as whether page loading has started or not etc)

Hope this will solve issue you have raised

Comment: Jeah this is one workaround, if nobody comes with better answer I will accept it, I was aware I could do it that way I only thought there might be something else...

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution: use `startActivityForResult(intent, 1)` instead of `startActivity(intent)` and check the `requestCode` and `resultCode` this way:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        //intent 1 was
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
             //successful
        } else {
             //not succusseful
        }
    }
}
```

This works for most sorts of Intent (email, camera, etc)

Comment: This solution was obsoleted with the new Activity Results API, see https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result