# Share Intent - Getting results, where it got shared and status?

Tags: android, android-intent

In my Android app, I'm using following code to share a photo with any app that can share it. So depending on what app is installed it can be shared with gmail, facebook, twitter and so on.

Here are my questions:

1. Can I get a result from Intent that tells where was this image shared?
2. Can I get the status of the upload of this share?
3. Can I at least know when the share dialog disappears and I get the focus back onto my app?

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/png");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mypackage.myapp/"+MainScreen.selectedCardId);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email body text");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share your card with:"));
```

Answer (score 6):

This question may be related to: [Successful share intent for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793825/successful-share-intent-for-android)

Basically it depends on the target app, whether they set a result and send back to your app or not. It's quite unreliable at this point from what I understand and I'm looking for a workaround too!