# How to confirm Android Share Intent is successful or complete

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, share, android-sharing

Is there a way to confirm if a Share intent in Android was successful or unsuccessful? (For example, if I share a Facebook post, I'd like to know if it was successfully posted or know if it was cancelled.)

Below is the Android intent code that I use to Share. Currently, it launches a dialog to allow the user to choose which app to share to:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);    
activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, title));
```

Comment: Why do you need to know if the user shared it?

Comment: It's for the purpose of tracking the users actions

Comment: You are aware that you are not allowed to incentivize share? And that you are not allowed to prefill the message parameter?

Comment: @WizKid I build a share intent using external url and i was looking for a solution to delete the image that is generated after the share intent is successful

Comment: Facebook may go and download it later.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Personally, I was about to say "use `startActivityForResult()`" and check what gets returned. However, as you can [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793825/successful-share-intent-for-android), it's not as simple as that. If the intent is cancelled by the user, the same number is returned as if the intent was completed (for most appications).

Ultimately, at the moment for a simpler Share intent **in general**, you cannot check if it's successful or not.

Comment: Thank you for the answer MDragon. If I want to specifically use Facebook/Twitter/E-mail for the share intent, how can I confirm if the share was successful?

Comment: For general share intents, you'll have to test all three of those out and see what they return for success and cancel. Twitter works at the very least, but as for Facebook, I doubt it does.

Comment: Now, this is *conjecture* and outside of the scope of this question, but "specific intents" may work. However, what kind of specific intents/activities are there that link to the Facebook+Twitter(+Email?) APIs and then return a value for success or failure? In other words, there's the possibility that - if you want to know if those succeed - you'll need to handle it yourself. However, if there are already specific intents (or activities) made for those purposes, use those.

Comment: I want to call api after user share successfully. so what i do ? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In case of FacebookShareDialog Build your dialog with requestCode            then onActivity check the Request code and Result code. For this there is one class in Facebook Sdk Name UiLifecycleHelper

in onCreate Method

```
uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, null);
uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




 FacebookDialog fbShardialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(
                        MainActivity.this)
                        .setLink("http://www.claro.com.ar/")
                        .setPicture("imagepath").setRequestCode(12)
                        .build();

                uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(fbShardialog.present());



OnActivityResult


 if (requestCode == 12) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //  show sucess message

        }
 else
//show failure message

    }
```

Comment: This class is no longer available in the most recent version of the SDK.