# Does ACTION_SEND return anything on successful share or on cancelled action by user?

Tags: android, android-intent

Before Marking it duplicate please read it below. This question was earlier asked around 4-5 years ago.

I have gone through [this question on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793825/successful-share-intent-for-android). But solution was not given so far so I just wanted to know anyone found any solution for this.

**Question is:**

How to check  if a user successfully completed a share intent or he has cancelled the operation? For instance if a user wanted to share an app via Facebook or gmail, so will **ACTION_SEND** action after successfull share intimate back to my current app?

**Note:** Please don't give answers for how to **create share intent** or **onActivityResult** .

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Successfully Sharing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }}
```

But this Toast is never occurring.Please suggest me any solution for this.

Comment: Did you read the accepted answer on the question you linked?

Comment: ITs the same try to use onActivityResult which is not happening I have checked.

Comment: Then you should tell us which app the user choosed that failed to give a respones. Android version. Manufacturer. Device model.

Comment: I have tried with it Micromax with MArshmallow version, HTC with KITKat version and they are returning nothing after sharing. I tried to share on gmail and slack , content was shared but there is no response in onActivityResult method as result =0 is returning everytime. @greenapps

Comment: `as result =0 is returning everytime` ??? Where do you see that result? You said that onActivityResult was not triggered. So i wonder what happens instead. There is no `result`parameter for onActivityResult.

Comment: The function will definitely trigger as we are using startACtivityforREsult to share the intent. but the parametrs what it is returning checked with Log . I mentioned that Toast is never occuring as result=0 is returning always. @greenapps